# R java File missing

Tags: android

I recently added "recyclerview" dependency in my project and synced it.After syncing i found my R.java file missing. Now android is not showing support for R statements in the project.Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Generally, a missing R file means that something is wrong with your gradle file. Can you post that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, do a "clean" on your project will also fix this.

Eclipse: Project -> Clean, then rebuild your project

Android Studio: Build-> Clean, then Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: I have tried that, works in eclipse but nit on studio.

Comment: I have added Build -> Clean for Android Studio. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Well Relax here is a Trick

Comment Every-line in `.java` File where your Using R reference,then Build your Project,It Will Rebuild R File,Now Uncomment then and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

i just copies the R file from another project.